# Is it possible to loop proc contents and produce a table for each entry?

Tags: macros, sas

Suppose, I have the following output from calling proc contents:

```
Name Type Format
  x    1    DATETIME
  y    2        $
```

Depending on the format I want to call different macros. Let's say I have two macros, %date(var = ) and %rest(var = ). Eventually, I would like to call the macro %date with name x and the macro %rest with name y. I hope it's more or less clear what I am trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but rather than trying to process the out of `PROC CONTENTS`, you would typically request an output data set from `PROC CONTENTS` and then process that further:

```
proc contents data=mydata out=mycontents noprint;
run;
```

The `NOPRINT` option suppresses the normal printed output. The `MYCONTENTS` data set will contain a row for each variable in the `MYDATA` data set, with columns for `type`, `length`, `format` etc. You can then process that further however you wish, calling your `%date()` macro or whatever.

EDIT:

Here is a more complete program showing how to add a `result` variable to the contents data set, using a separate macro for each data type. Note that there's no particular need to use macros in this code.

```
%macro num_macro();
    result = 'I''m a numeric';
%mend;

%macro char_macro();
    result = 'I''m a character';
%mend;

data in;
  attrib datevar length=8 format=date9.;
  attrib charvar length=$ 20;
  attrib numvar length=8;
run;

proc contents data=in out=contents noprint;
run;

data contents_with_result;
  length result $ 40;
  set contents (keep = name type);
  if type=1 then do;
    %num_macro();
  end;
  else do;
    %char_macro();
  end;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

This uses the two small macros to encapsulate the different code required for each data type, but note that this isn't calling the macros once per record in the data set - the macros are called exactly once each when the data step is being parsed/compiled, and then the code the macros generated is executed once per record in the input data set.

There are ways to have a macro called once per record in an input data set, but that approach is only needed in quite specialised cases. If you want to do some per-record processing on data that is already in a data set, you should almost always do it with a data step if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you be more specific? How would you use mycontents? I am not sure in what environment I can call macros conditional on the type. Thank you

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, but something like 'data _null_; set mycontents; if format='date' then call execute('%date(var=' || name || ');'); run;', for example. You can look up the docs for CALL EXECUTE. It can also be done in a more pure macro way, depending on taste. Are you trying to generate one call per variable, or just one call to %date for all the date vars and one call to %rest for all the non-date vars?

Comment: As a start, I would like to add a column result to the output of proc contents. The value of the column result is set by calling one of the two macros depending on name. How would you do this? I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: I've edited my answer to expand out the example code a bit more. This is becoming a very wide-ranging question now, though!

Comment: @ Chris Long. This works perfect. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @ Chris Long. One more question if you have time. How would you tackle the following prolem. If Name from proc contents is used to call a macro, which in turn calls another dataset. The macro would take the following form %some_macro(Name, Dataset, Library). Moreover the Output of the macro Comes from a proc SQL and is the number of distinct vaues in a variable (Name). Sorry, I hope it's still clear what I mean.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't very clear. It sounds like you just want some code to determine the count of distinct values of each variable... if that's the ultimate goal, going via PROC CONTENTS and multiple macros and PROC SQL is not the way to do it. If the ultimate goal is something else, I can't see it.

Comment: @ Chris Long. Totally understandable ;-) Stil, thanks for trying. I tried to rephrase my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031936/how-to-call-a-macro-that-in-turn-updates-an-into-statement