# How to call a macro in a data step that updates a macro variable and use that value immediately?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

The following example is very simple and might be solvable in an easier way. However, I am interested in making it work. The following example is based on the cars-dataset of the sashelp-library. First, I have a macro called fun:

```
proc contents data = sashelp.cars out = mycontents;
run;

%macro fun(var);
proc sql noprint;
        select count(distinct(&var.))
        into :obs
        from sashelp.cars;
quit;
%mend;
```

Now I want to call the macro but only to update obs (from the input statement). I use:

```
data work.test;
set mycontents;
if name ne "Type" then do;
      call execute('%nrstr(%fun('||name||');');
      new = &obs;
end;
else new = 5;
```

run;

In short, this should iterate the rows of the mycontents. Then call one (of several) macros depending on name, which updates obs. Then I can simply populate the new column new with obs. However, obs stays the same value for all names, which is the value from the last variable.

Comment: Good question, and well written!

Comment: @Snorehorse (1) The title doesn't need to tell that it's a SAS question - the tag does that.  (On google, for example, the tag will appear along with the page.)

Comment: (2) I didn't think `CALL EXECUTE` was important to the question; the title above is a bit broader and will pick up more hits, and `CALL EXECUTE` will trigger this post anyway as it's in the body. And i'll add the space, you're correct there.

Comment: And if you like `dosubl` look up "Run_MACRO Run!" which is a very good paper on the more advanced use of it.

Comment: Update I am not super happy with either, but `define` `declare` etc. isn't great either, and any other solution is more wordy, no?  (I don't remember what word you used, so maybe I'm missing something...)  `Immediately` is accurate, I think; immediately as opposed to in the next data step.  (could say `in the same data step` but that's wordy, not searchable, and won't tend to be read anyway as it's so far into the title)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the problem is twofold.

First, you cannot use `CALL EXECUTE` in this context because that doesn't execute until *after* the data step has completed running: so anything depending on `&obs` will not be able to get an updated value for that.  You'll have to use [`dosubl`](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/032-2013.pdf).

Second, you need to use `symget('obs')`, not `&obs`, if you want to get an updated value mid-data step.  `&obs` will resolve when the data step is compiled, so it cannot change during execution; but `symget(obs)` instructs the data step to query the symbol table during execution.

Here's an example of doing this with `dosubl`, minimally changed from your example.  Note the `%global` statement to make sure `obs` is available to us in the data step (there are other ways to do this to get it back that are better - namely, wrapping this in a `fcmp` function and using `run_macro` - but this is closest to how you do it).

```
proc contents data = sashelp.cars out = mycontents;
run;

%macro fun(var);
%global obs;
proc sql noprint;
        select count(distinct(&var.))
        into :obs
        from sashelp.cars;
quit;
%mend;

data work.test;
set mycontents;
if name ne "Type" then do;
      rc = dosubl(cats('%fun(',name,')'));
      new = symgetn('obs');
end;
else new = 5;
run;
```

Comment: @ Joe. Thank you so much for helping me. I'm quite new to SAS and wasn't aware of these functions. I'll try it as soon as I'm back at work. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, always happy to help with well written questions!

Comment: Don't you want use symgetN so NEW will be numeric?